# Why does Peter Venkman call Ray Stantz "Francine"?

Tags: reference, ghostbusters

Near the beginning of *Ghostbusters*, there is a scene where the protagonists encounter an apparition in the New York Public Library.  Ray Stantz and Egon Spengler can't decide what to do, so Peter Venkman draws them into a private conference, pulling Ray by the ear and saying,

> Could you just come over here for a second, please? Right over here. Come here, Francine! Come here. What do we do?

Why does Peter call Ray "Francine"?  Is he just using a generic feminine name to ridicule Ray's dainty handling of the situation, or is "Francine" a reference to something or someone specific?

Comment: According to "the Internet", the scene was ad-libbed and thus does not mean anything, the scene was perfectly scripted, and everything has a meaning, "Francis" is Ray's middle name, "Francine" is Ray's middle name, "Francine" is Ray's actual first name, "Francine" is a reference to *The Nanny* (never mind the fact the show didn't exist at the time), and my personal favorite: "This is just Murray's humor, and if you would get his humor, you would get his joke" – but without explaining the joke, thus implying the person asking the question does not get the humor and also is not worthy of it.

Comment: I can confirm that the line is not in [the original shooting script](https://www.spookcentral.tk/media/sclib/gb1_script_1983-10-07_makinggb.pdf), so it probably is an ad-lib.  But that doesn't mean it isn't a reference to something specific.

Answer (score 3):

In-universe it was confirmed (on the alternate cover of [Ghostbusters Year One #2](https://ghostbusters.fandom.com/wiki/IDW_Publishing_Comics-_Ghostbusters_Year_One_2)) that Ray's full name is

> *[R]**aymond Franc**[is?ine?]*.

Peter is presumably making a reference to his middle name, either directly or mockingly.

[image]

Comment: That comic was published 36 years after the film.  Is there any evidence that whoever came up with the line in the film was deliberately referencing Ray's middle name?  Or is this a retcon on the part of the author of the comic?

Comment: @Psychonaut - definitely a retcon